# How can I use an alias thats defined in a header file, in the return type (signature) of a function in the .cpp file?

Tags: c++, alias, signature, using, using-declaration

I have a class, `Tracker`, where I declare an alias

From `Tracker.h`:

```
class Tracker {
...
using ArgsMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
std::shared_ptr<ArgsMap> getArgsMapForTask(std::string task);
...
}
```

In the .cpp file, where I define the function:

```
#include Tracker.h
...
// ArgsMap here gives error: Use of undeclared identifier 'ArgsMap' 
std::shared_ptr<ArgsMap> Tracker::getArgsMapForTask(std::string taskName)
{
ArgsMap a; // this gives no error, compiler recognizes ArgsMap
}
```

How can I use `ArgsMap` in the function signature?

Comment: Consider that having an header file and including it via `#include` is just like copying and pasting its contante in place of the `#include`.

Comment: I am including the header, but I still get a compiler error for the alias being unrecognized if its used in the return type

Comment: Can you please show us the error _and_ the header file? Please, see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sure. I updated the question to include both, using the actual code with the error

Comment: I think there's a typo. `StudioTasksTracker` should be `Tracker`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not that the alias is in the header file, that's totally irrelevant.

The problem is that the alias is defined in the scope of the class, so you need to qualify it if you want to use it outside of the class: `Tracker::ArgsMap`.